# How to Create ClickOnce Extension for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, single-sign-on, clickonce

- Some of our clients are adopting Google Chrome and ditching IE/Edge
  as the official browser.
- All of our application that is dependent on ClickOnce deployment and
  SSO login doesn't work in Chrome.
- The use of third party extensions is not approved.
- We need to build our own extension that the company would maintain.

Can anyone help with the workflow for an extension to enable ClickOnce and SSO in Chrome?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? We are running in to the same issue.

Comment: Update: Microsoft Edge is reintroducing Click Once as optional from ver77+ and then from ver8x, it's turning it on by default.